# extracting an element using Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

```
    <a id="yui_3_4_1_1_1329966665861_8510" class="buy-as-gift-link" 
            data-bntrack="buyasgift" href="#purchase=9780345527721"></a>
```

need to extract "#purchase=9780345527721" from this element using Xpath

- this is what i have done till now :

  $nodelist_nook = trim($xpath_nook->query("//a[@class='buy-as-gift-link']")->item(0)->nodeValue);

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
//a[@id='yui_3_4_1_1_1329966665861_8510']/@href
```

This XPath expression selects all `href` attributes of all `a` elements that have an `id` attribute with string value `"yui_3_4_1_1_1329966665861_8510"`.

In case you want to get not the attribute node (we hope that no two elements exist with the same value for `id`) but just its string value, this can be obtained as result of evaluating the following XPath expression:

```
string(//a[@id='yui_3_4_1_1_1329966665861_8510']/@href)
```